# I got "permission denied" while trying to write-flash a firmware on the ESP32-wroom-32

Tags: esp32, micropython

As first step, I downloaded the micropython firmware for generic ESP32 boards and selected a path to store the file. Then, realizing that I had installed the python interpreter (3.11.14 version), I installed the esptool.py with pip install esptool and no problems occured. After that, I succesfully executed the command "esptool –port COM3 erase_flash", but not the command "esptool --chip esp32 --port COM3 --baud 460800 write_flash 0x1000 C:\Users\JASS2\firmwareESP32". A weird detail is that I cannot execute these commands with "esptool.py" despite having esptool installed. With the write_flash command I get the following error:

usage: esptool write_flash [-h] [--erase-all] [--flash_freq {keep,80m,60m,48m,40m,30m,26m,24m,20m,16m,15m,12m}]
[--flash_mode {keep,qio,qout,dio,dout}]
[--flash_size {detect,keep,256KB,512KB,1MB,2MB,2MB-c1,4MB,4MB-c1,8MB,16MB,32MB,64MB,128MB}]
[--spi-connection SPI_CONNECTION] [--no-progress] [--verify] [--encrypt]
[--encrypt-files   [  ...]] [--ignore-flash-encryption-efuse-setting]
[--force] [--compress | --no-compress]
  [  ...]
esptool write_flash: error: argument  : [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\JASS2\\firmwareESP32'

[version of the firmware I downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mQAy.png)

Tried changing the path of the micropython firmware and giving all the permissions to the folder with the properties menu but I still have the problem.

I thought these options could let me write the firmware but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You've made a mistake in specifying the path. Currently you're specifying the path to the folder in which the firmware is located. However, you should specify the path to the firmware itself, i.e.:
`esptool --chip esp32 --port COM3 --baud 460800 write_flash 0x1000 C:\Users\JASS2\firmwareESP32\ESP32_GENERIC-20240105-v1.22.1`
instead of
`esptool --chip esp32 --port COM3 --baud 460800 write_flash 0x1000 C:\Users\JASS2\firmwareESP32`

Make sure to use the right path to the firmware. Since you're on Windows, you can right click the firmware file and then click "Copy as Path" to get the right path.